# Test if nodes are empty or contain NULL using template match

Tags: xml, xslt

Edit to the XML

I am trying to figure out how test if nodes do not exist or contain the word NULL using template matching.  Currently I am using a <xsl:choose> test in my matched template.  Is there a more efficient way to do this test?

In the XML if the  or  nodes do not eixt, or contain the word NULL then I want to skip that  node completely and print out a statement saying why that node is incorrect (i.e. "The TITLE does not exist" or "The CONTENT is NULL").

In the XML I have the third and fourth  node should not display any content and instead print a statement saying why content was not displayed.

Here is an example of the XML I am using to test:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FIGURES>
  <FIGURE>
    <TITLE>Title 1</TITLE>
    <DESC>Description 1</DESC>
    <CONTENT>Content 1</CONTENT>
  </FIGURE>
  <FIGURE>
    <TITLE>Title 2</TITLE>
    <DESC>Description 2</DESC>
    <CONTENT>Content 2</CONTENT>
  </FIGURE>
  <FIGURE>
    <DESC>Description 3</DESC>
    <CONTENT>Content 3</CONTENT>
  </FIGURE>
  <FIGURE>
    <TITLE>Title 4</TITLE>
    <DESC>Description 4</DESC>
    <CONTENT>NULL</CONTENT>
  </FIGURE>     
  <FIGURE>
    <TITLE>Title 5</TITLE>
    <DESC>Description 5</DESC>
    <CONTENT>Content 5</CONTENT>
  </FIGURE>
</FIGURES>
```

Here is the XSLT I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <div class="container">
   <xsl:apply-templates />
 </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FIGURES">
  <ul class="list">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="FIGURE" mode="titles" />
  </ul>  
  <div class="content">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="FIGURE" mode="content" />
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FIGURE" mode="titles">
  <xsl:choose>
    <!-- Check to see if the TITLE field is empty -->
    <xsl:when test="translate(./TITLE,' ', '') = ''">The TITLE node is empty</xsl:when>                      
    <!-- Check to see if the TITLE field is NULL -->
    <xsl:when test="normalize-space(./TITLE) = 'NULL'">The TITLE node is NULL</xsl:when> 
    <!-- Check to see if the CONTENT field is empty -->
    <xsl:when test="translate(./CONTENT,' ', '') = ''">The CONTENT node is empty</xsl:when>
    <!-- Check to see if the CONTENT field is NULL -->
    <xsl:when test="normalize-space(./CONTENT) = 'NULL'">The CONTENT node is NULL</xsl:when>                                            
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <li>
        <a href="#section-{position()}">
          <h3><xsl:value-of select="TITLE" /></h3>
        </a>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="DESC" /></p>
      </li>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FIGURE" mode="content">
  <xsl:choose>
    <!-- Check to see if the TITLE field is empty -->
    <xsl:when test="translate(./TITLE,' ', '') = ''">The TITLE node is empty</xsl:when>                      
    <!-- Check to see if the TITLE field is NULL -->
    <xsl:when test="normalize-space(./TITLE) = 'NULL'">The TITLE node is NULL</xsl:when> 
    <!-- Check to see if the CONTENT field is empty -->
    <xsl:when test="translate(./CONTENT,' ', '') = ''">The CONTENT node is empty</xsl:when>
    <!-- Check to see if the CONTENT field is NULL -->
    <xsl:when test="normalize-space(./CONTENT) = 'NULL'">The CONTENT node is NULL</xsl:when>                                            
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <div id="section-{position()}">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="CONTENT" /></p>
      </div>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will essentially produce the same result as your XSLT and avoid the use of `xsl:choose`. Please give it a try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <div class="container">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="FIGURES">
    <ul class="list">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="FIGURE" mode="titles" />
    </ul>
    <div class="content">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="FIGURE" mode="content" />
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="FIGURE" mode="titles">
    <li>
      <a href="#section-{position()}">
        <h3>
          <xsl:value-of select="TITLE" />
        </h3>
      </a>
      <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="DESC" />
      </p>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template 
      match="FIGURE[ *[self::TITLE or self::CONTENT]
                      [not(normalize-space(.)) or normalize-space(.) = 'NULL']
                   ]"
      mode="titles">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="TITLE | CONTENT" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="FIGURE" mode="content">
    <div id="section-{position()}">
      <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="CONTENT" />
      </p>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template 
      match="FIGURE[ *[self::TITLE or self::CONTENT]
                      [not(normalize-space(.)) or normalize-space(.) = 'NULL']
                   ]"
      mode="content">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="TITLE | CONTENT" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TITLE | CONTENT" />

  <xsl:template match="*[self::TITLE or self::CONTENT][not(normalize-space(.))]">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('The ', local-name(), ' node is empty')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[self::TITLE or self::CONTENT][normalize-space(.) = 'NULL']">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('The ', local-name(), ' node is NULL')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Please give it a try.
```

Comment: Apolgies to you as well.  This solution works for my original problem but I made a mistake in posting the issue.  When an XML node contains no value it does not display. For example if <TITLE> has no value it will not display as <TITLE></TITLE>.  That node will simply not exist in the XML.  I have been stuck on getting this solution to work when the <TITLE> or <CONTENT> node do not exist.  Sorry for the improper posting in my XML example earlier.  I have editted it to reflect the situation.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a shorter transformation that produces the same result, and doesn't use any conditional XSLT instructions**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <div class="container">
       <ul class="list">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </ul>
       <div class="content">
           <xsl:apply-templates mode="content"/>
         </div>
     </div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="FIGURE">
   <li>
     <a href="#section-{position()}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="TITLE"/>
     </a>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="DESC"/>
   </li>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="TITLE">
   <h3><xsl:value-of select="."/></h3>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="DESC">
   <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="FIGURE[*[. = 'NULL' or not(normalize-space())]]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[. = 'NULL' or not(normalize-space())]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="FIGURE/*[. = 'NULL']">
  The <xsl:value-of select="name()"/> node is NULL.
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="FIGURE/*[not(normalize-space())]">
  The <xsl:value-of select="name()"/> node is empty.
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="FIGURE[not(*[. = 'NULL' or not(normalize-space())])]" mode="content">
      <div id="section-{position()}">
         <p><xsl:value-of select="CONTENT"/></p>
      </div>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="FIGURE" mode="content"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<FIGURES>
    <FIGURE>
        <TITLE>Title 1</TITLE>
        <DESC>Description 1</DESC>
        <CONTENT>Content 1</CONTENT>
    </FIGURE>
    <FIGURE>
        <TITLE>Title 2</TITLE>
        <DESC>Description 2</DESC>
        <CONTENT>Content 2</CONTENT>
    </FIGURE>
    <FIGURE>
        <TITLE></TITLE>
        <DESC>Description 3</DESC>
        <CONTENT>Content 3</CONTENT>
    </FIGURE>
    <FIGURE>
        <TITLE>Title 4</TITLE>
        <DESC>Description 4</DESC>
        <CONTENT>NULL</CONTENT>
    </FIGURE>
    <FIGURE>
        <TITLE>Title 5</TITLE>
        <DESC>Description 5</DESC>
        <CONTENT>Content 5</CONTENT>
    </FIGURE>
</FIGURES>
```

**the same result is produced as with the originally provided transformation:**

```
<div class="container">
   <ul class="list">
      <li>
         <a href="#section-1">
            <h3>Title 1</h3>
         </a>
         <p>Description 1</p>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#section-2">
            <h3>Title 2</h3>
         </a>
         <p>Description 2</p>
      </li>
  The TITLE node is empty.

  The CONTENT node is NULL.
 <li>
         <a href="#section-5">
            <h3>Title 5</h3>
         </a>
         <p>Description 5</p>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <div class="content">
      <div id="section-1">
         <p>Content 1</p>
      </div>
      <div id="section-2">
         <p>Content 2</p>
      </div>
      <div id="section-5">
         <p>Content 5</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I apologize, I made a mistake in the XML I originally posted.  I editted the question and XML to reflect this.  I have been trying to anticipate the <TITLE> node containing no value but actually the <TITLE> node will not exist if it has not value.  I think that is why I have been having trouble with this solution which otherwise works.